# sending unicode over TCP sockets, what about endianness

Tags: c, sockets, unicode, tcp

I read a string with some unicode symbols (UTF8) in c. The ones I read is stored in 3 bytes, so these characters can't be stored in a single byte, so I'm worried about the endianness of these when sent over TCP socket using the functions write and read. Do I need to do anything particular with them to make sure the machine that reads from the stream interprets these unicode characters correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send it as a byte array. Endianness should not be issue for UTF8 encoded strings, since those are byte oriented. Endianness matters for example when you have two bytes and you need to interpret them as single value. If you have to interpret these two bytes individually, endianness is not an issue.

More info: http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html

> Q: Is the UTF-8 encoding scheme the same irrespective of whether the
>   underlying processor is little endian or big endian?
>
> A: Yes. Since UTF-8 is interpreted as a sequence of bytes, there is no
>   endian problem as there is for encoding forms that use 16-bit or
>   32-bit code units. Where a BOM is used with UTF-8, it is only used as
>   an encoding signature to distinguish UTF-8 from other encodings — it
>   has nothing to do with byte order.  [AF]

Comment: What does it mean the strings are UTF8 encoded? And this UTF8 character is stored as 3 bytes!

Comment: @HorseSMith: I mean string as such means not much right? When you have a text it must be stored somehow on computer. The way it gets stored depends on the encoding you use, e.g., UTF 8

Comment: So you're saying I shouldn't worry about the endianness when transferring such strings over TCP?

Comment: @HorseSMith: Endian only applies to numeric values larger than 1 byte in size. UTF-8 does not suffer from endian because it is an 8-bit encoding scheme, whereas UTF-16 and UTF-32 are 16-bit and 32-bit encoding schemes, respectively. UTF-8 encodes a given Unicode codepoint using either 1, 2, 3 or 4 *8-bit codeunits*, so it does not suffer from endian. UTF-16 encodes using either 1 or 2 *16-bit codeunits*, and UTF-32 encodes using 1 *32-bit codeunit*, so they both suffer from endian on the individual codeunits. Which is why there are UTF-16LE, UTF-16BE, UTF-32LE, and UTF-32BE encodings defined.